# How do I paint the background of TStringGrid

Tags: delphi, paint, tstringgrid

I do custom drawing of a Delphi TStringGrid using the OnDrawCell event.
There is no problem with the area covered by cells, but how do I paint the background right of the rightmost column and below the last row ?

(Edit)
Painting is not really necessary, I just want to set the color used for background.
I am using XE2 and investigating VCL styles.
Even in default drawing, setting Colors in a stringgrid, seams to have no effect at all.

TIA

Comment: OK I finally found it.

The problem was the DrawingStyle property of TStringGrid that defaults to gdsThemed.
Setting it to gdsClassic makes the grids Color property kick in - also for the background.
Issue solved.

Thanks to Andreas for a way to completely control the background painting process, but it's an overkill for my issue.

rgds TheRoadrunner

Answer (score 2):

This is some code I found with google (It is not from me, I could not find the name of the author, maybe it comes from StackExchange on some way...). It defines a descendant from TStringGrid and implements a new background drawing. (The example uses a bitmap, but you easily can change that...)

```
  type
  TStringGrid = class(Grids.TStringGrid)
  private
    FGraphic: TGraphic;
    FStretched: Boolean;
    function BackgroundVisible(var ClipRect: TRect): Boolean;
    procedure PaintBackground;
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
    procedure Resize; override;
    procedure TopLeftChanged; override;
  public
    property BackgroundGraphic: TGraphic read FGraphic write FGraphic;
    property BackgroundStretched: Boolean read FStretched write FStretched;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    StringGrid: TStringGrid;
    Image: TImage;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TStringGrid }

function TStringGrid.BackgroundVisible(var ClipRect: TRect): Boolean;
var
  Info: TGridDrawInfo;
  R: TRect;
begin
  CalcDrawInfo(Info);
  SetRect(ClipRect, 0, 0, Info.Horz.GridBoundary, Info.Vert.GridBoundary);
  R := ClientRect;
  Result := (ClipRect.Right < R.Right) or (ClipRect.Bottom < R.Bottom);
end;

procedure TStringGrid.Paint;
begin
  inherited Paint;
  PaintBackground;
end;

procedure TStringGrid.PaintBackground;
var
  R: TRect;
begin
  if (FGraphic <> nil) and BackgroundVisible(R) then
  begin
    with R do
      ExcludeClipRect(Canvas.Handle, Left, Top, Right, Bottom);
    if FStretched then
      Canvas.StretchDraw(ClientRect, FGraphic)
    else
      Canvas.Draw(0, 0, FGraphic);
  end;
end;

procedure TStringGrid.Resize;
begin
  inherited Resize;
  PaintBackground;
end;

procedure TStringGrid.TopLeftChanged;
begin
  inherited TopLeftChanged;
  PaintBackground;
end;

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Usage: 
  StringGrid.BackgroundGraphic := Image.Picture.Graphic;
  StringGrid.BackgroundStretched := True;
end;
```

Comment: Its from an answer by NGLN here on SO. [delphi-stringgrid-with-picture-in-background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285659/delphi-stringgrid-with-picture-in-background). It's supposed to be used with a picture in the background.

Comment: OK, thank you! It sould be no problem to use the code to draw other backgrounds onto the grid.

Comment: No problem at all, but to answer the question you can elaborate a little more how to draw a background color.

Comment: @Andreas And you could have added the link yourself. It is customary to attribute information you re-iterate to its source.

Comment: @LU RD: The question was edited. In the beginning there was no hint  that it is only the color of the background to be painted.

Comment: @Marjan: Yes, of course you are right. I did not find the link in SO by myself. Sorry.

Comment: @Andreas: :-) I tend to keep bookmarks of stuff I used. With Google Chrome it is very easy to search through them... and I only get hit with stuff I bookmarked (instead of everything else on the web).