# Transparent color in StringGrid

Tags: delphi, pascal, lazarus, freepascal, stringgrid

I fill cells in StringGrid green color

```
procedure TForm1.StringGridDrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
  Rect: TRect; State: TGridDrawState);
begin

StringGrid.Canvas.Brush.Color := clGreen;
StringGrid.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);

StringGrid.Canvas.TextOut(Rect.Left + 2, Rect.Top + 2, AGrid.Cells[ACol, ARow]);

end;
```

My StringGrid has black color. I would like to fill cell transparent color (for example 50%).

How can I do this?

I should draw rectangle? Or I should create bitmap and put in to cell?

Can you help me?:)

Imean effect like this:
[image]

Comment: I do not understand what you have and what you want to do....

Comment: I'd like to color the cell was transparent - alpha, whatever;)

Comment: You mean that you want to partially see the background of the form/panel or whatover into which the grid is inserted?

Comment: Eventualy background of the StringGrid when StringGrid.Color:=whatever; and I have colored cell.

Comment: Take a look at [this question-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285659/delphi-stringgrid-with-picture-in-background). Use a combination of AR and NGLN answers.

Comment: I have done some testing and will post an answer later today, but please tell me: Which Delphi version? Do you plan to use styles (XE2 onward)? Because you have tagged also freepascal, I assume you target Windows (IOW, VCL) and not mobile (FMX)?

Comment: I wonder why it is so hard to answer the few simple questions in my previous comment. I know you have been around at least twice since then. Maybe you are not interested anymore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With inspiration from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285659/delphi-stringgrid-with-picture-in-background) I first created a `TStringGrid` with an image in the background. Then I added a tranparent color using `WinApi.Windows.AlphaBlend()` for the selected cells and similarily for the fixed cells. The end result is this:

[image]

The transparent "selected" color is done as a 1 pixel bitmap:

```
type
  TStringGrid = class(Vcl.Grids.TStringGrid)
  private
    FBackG: TBitmap;
    FForeG: TBitmap;
  ...

procedure TForm5.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  sg.FForeG.Free;
  sg.FForeG := TBitmap.Create;
  sg.FForeG.SetSize(1, 1);
  sg.FForeG.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
  sg.FForeG.Canvas.Pixels[0, 0] := $00FF00;  // BGR
end;
```

And the bitmap is applied for "selected" cells (`gdSelected in State`) in the `OnDrawCell` event

```
procedure TForm5.sgDrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer; Rect: TRect;
  State: TGridDrawState);
var
  sg: TStringGrid;
  r: TRect;
  success:boolean;
begin
  if not (Sender is TStringGrid) then Exit;
  sg := Sender as TStringGrid;

  r := Rect;
  r.Left := r.Left-4; // Might not be needed, depending on Delphi version?

  // Clear the cell
  sg.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlack;
  sg.Canvas.FillRect(r);

  // Copy background to cell
  BitBlt(sg.Canvas.Handle,
    r.Left, r.Top, r.Right - r.Left, r.Bottom - r.Top,
    sg.FBackG.Canvas.Handle, r.Left, r.Top, SRCCOPY);

    // Draw fixed column or row cell(s)
  if gdFixed in State then
  begin
    success := Winapi.Windows.AlphaBlend(sg.Canvas.Handle,
      r.Left, r.Top, r.Right - r.Left, r.Bottom - r.Top,
      sg.FHeadG.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, 1, 23, BlendFunc);
  end;

  // Draw selected cell(s)
  if gdSelected in State then
  begin
    success := Winapi.Windows.AlphaBlend(sg.Canvas.Handle,
      r.Left, r.Top, r.Right - r.Left, r.Bottom - r.Top,
      sg.FForeG.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, 1, 1, BlendFunc);
  end;

  // Draw the text
  r := Rect;
  sg.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
  DrawText(sg.Canvas.Handle, sg.Cells[ACol, ARow],
    length(sg.Cells[ACol, ARow]), r,
    DT_SINGLELINE or DT_VCENTER or DT_END_ELLIPSIS);
end;
```

The `BlendFunc: _BLENDFUNCTION;` structure can be declared in the `TStringGrid` subclass or elsewhere where it is accessible, I declared it in the form and initialized it in the forms `OnCreate` event:

```
  BlendFunc.BlendOp := AC_SRC_OVER;
  BlendFunc.BlendFlags := 0;
  BlendFunc.SourceConstantAlpha := 128;  // This determines opacity
  BlendFunc.AlphaFormat := AC_SRC_ALPHA;
```

Now, you may ask, how come a 1-pixel bitmap works, and the answer is in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183351(v=vs.85).aspx) for `AlphaBlend()`:

> If the source rectangle and destination rectangle are not the same
>   size, the source bitmap is stretched to match the destination
>   rectangle.

This is useful since the cell rectangles usually varies in size.

The header row and column are similarily drawn in the `OnDrawCell` on condition `if gdFixed in State` and here another bitmap is used. It is a 1 pixel wide and 23 pixels high bitmap I made separately in a graphics drawing program.

[image]

Yes! The tiny thing above is the image.